# How to Uglify/minify scss into a smaller scss file

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I want to combine all `.scss` files into one `.scss` file and minify and uglify the result. This is what I have so far.

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
const sass = require('gulp-scss-combine');
import * as concat from 'gulp-concat';

import Config from '../../config';

export = () => {
  // read all files in css components folder folder
  return gulp.src([`${Config.APP_SRC}/css/components/*.scss`, `${Config.APP_SRC}/css/components/**/*.scss`])
    .pipe(concat('bundled.scss')) // Merge all files into bundled.scss
    .pipe(sass())  // Remove @import statements from the output
// What can I pipe here to minify the scss?
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${Config.DIST_DIR}/${Config.LIB_CLIENT}/css/exportedCSS`)); //
};
```

I want to minify the scss and not convert it to a css file because other files need it to be a scss since they import variables from it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to minify SCSS files? SCSS is only intended for use during development; in production, your stylesheets should all be compiled to CSS.

Comment: SCSS adds no weight to your website. In fact your site should never see SCSS or SASS files. The only thing you need to minify is your CSS that is outputted from the SCSS files that are compiled